# "ENOTEMPTY undeclared" compilation error

Tags: c, posix

I have to delete the file/directory pointed to by `path`. So I call `remove(path)`, and if this fails with `ENOTEMPTY`, then it is a non-empty directory and I handle it accordingly.

```
status = remove(path);
if (status == -1 && errno == ENOTEMPTY)
    ftw(path, recursive_dir_delete, 64);
```

On compilation, I get `ENOTEMPTY undeclared`. `ENOTEMPTY` is defined in unistd.h (`man 2 rmdir`), which I have #included, but still I get the error. What is the correct way of checking if errno was set to `ENOTEMPTY`?

gcc 4.6.3, 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Isn't it defined in `<errno.h>` instead?

Comment: yes it is. thanks. wanna submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error constants are declared in the C standard header `<errno.h>`. You have to `#include` that file in your project.